# Skipping if statements

Tags: php, phpmailer, contact-form

I'm building a contact form for a car dealers website.

For this I have 2 email templates; an auto responder that goes to the customer and an enquiry one that goes the dealer.

I'm using PHPMailer and have it setup so that if the send of the auto responder was successful, it then sends the enquiry email.

The dealer has many brands and 2 locations, so the form will have to go to a specific set of emails depending on the brand and location.

I have used this template many times before and it has worked.

**EDIT : If I place an addAddress outside the if statement, it sends the enquiry email, so theres a problem with the if statement, but im not sure what.**

My problem now is that the if statement is being skipped over and the only email being sent is the auto responder.

This is my full mail.php file - https://pastebin.com/fPr5Q0Pf

The if statment im using is:

```
    if ($brand == "Brand1") {
            $mail->addAddress('brand1@example.com');      
    }
    else if ($brand == "Brand2" && $location == "Location1") {
            $mail->addAddress('brand2loc1@example.com'); // For data tracking      
        }
   else if ($brand == "Brand2" && $location == "Location2") {
            $mail->addAddress('brand2loc2@example.com');    
        }
```

Comment: Did you debug $brand data came or not?

Comment: @AmanurRahman Yes, it has the correct brand name.

Comment: Use === instead of == and tell me what it says

Comment: @iftikharyk Same result. I just get the auto responder email sent.

Comment: Can you provide a small working program where it can be tested?

Answer (score 1):

You say,

```
@AmanurRahman Yes, it has the correct brand name. – Harry
```

But @Synchro has the right of it: *the value of `$brand` has to be incorrect*.

One way this can happen if it is a SELECT box and an OPTION has an extra space:

```
<option> Valkris</option>
```

So, try debugging the values using `var_dump()` - *better yet, get a proper IDE/XDebug connection working!*, or rewrite the code so that it tells you what it is happening:

```
if ($brand == "Brand1") {
    $mail->addAddress('brand1@example.com');      
}
else if ($brand == "Brand2" && $location == "Location1") {
    $mail->addAddress('brand2loc1@example.com'); // For data tracking      
}
else if ($brand == "Brand2" && $location == "Location2") {
    $mail->addAddress('brand2loc2@example.com');    
} else {
    die("Well, guess what. '{$brand}' and '{$location}' did not check.");
}
die("If you can read this, then the problem is not with the IFs");
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way for those `if` statements to fail is if `$brand` and `$location` do not contain the values you're checking for, so double-check your values.

Another way they can appear to not work is if the addresses you're adding are invalid, in which case the calls to `addAddress` will return false, but you're not checking those.